# CI's upload class isnt working?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, upload, multipart

Of course by that I mean I'm doing something wrong with it. I posted a question before similar to this one and got some answers. Well based on those answers (I wasn't using CI's class now I am) I'm having a new problem. Any help would be appreciated.

PHP

```
 public function do_upload () {

    $scopeId = $this->input->get('id');

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        echo 'error';                         <----- This is what is showing up
        // uploading failed. $error will holds the errors.
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
        // uploading successfull, now do your further actions

        redirect(site_url('discovery/scopeDetails?scID='.$scopeId.''));
    }

    echo $error;
}
```

HTML Form

```
 <div id="upload">
    <?=form_open_multipart('discovery/do_upload');?>
 <input name="userfile" size="40" type="file" />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</div>
```

With the form i usually would just use straight HTML but I tried doing EXACTLY what http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html told me to do.

Comment: What does $error contain? I would first check that. Then make sure your upload directory has write permissions.

Comment: How do i do the second part of that?

Comment: do you have an upload config file? Somewhere to specify your upload directory? Like this: $config['upload_dir'] = '/home/somesite/www/media/uploads/'; you then check that directory in your ftp or repo and make sure it has chmod 777 applied. right click properties on the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the problem is your upload folder. Make sure it exists and set it's permissions to 777.

If that's not the problem then use `print_r($error)` to see what's wrong.

Comment: hmmm, it says i did not select a file to upload

Comment: also make sure to close the form with `</form>`

Comment: I did. And like i said, i copied it straight from CI's site to make sure it wasnt something i was doing. (i put in the /form just now)

Comment: new error -- The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.

Comment: Qouting the documentation:  "You'll need a destination folder for your uploaded images. Create a folder at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called uploads and set its file permissions to 777."

Comment: Im working on setting them. I was just using the built in FTP with notepad++. Trying to connect to server with filezilla.

Comment: Ok. Just my opinion that might help you: 1) Try test these things locally first. (Lookup WAMP/XAMPP for Windows or MAMP for Mac if you don't know what I'm talking about). 2) I used to code PHP in notepad++ too, but learning VIM or using an IDE like Eclipse/NetBeans (or both!) can do wonders for your productivity.

Comment: Mmk, thanks. And i have wamp. Working for a guy that set up a server and ive had lots of problems with it. But ill check out those others.

Answer (score 0):

I had never experienced anything like that. My friend suggested to replace upload.php a new library with the old. so try it:

folder path "system/libraries/".
download and replace the file "upload.php"

http://www.4shared.com/file/BZci40l8/Upload.html

good luck! :D